# Node.JS - Reversing Massive Arrays Efficiently?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reverse

I have an array with two thousand single-character strings.

```
["f", "j", "w", "/", ":", "u", "9", etc...]
```

I can reverse this with `array.reverse()`. But two thousand things being reversed takes at least 5-7 seconds on my VPS. How can I make this task more efficient?

Comment: The question is; What is *this*? What are trying to do?

Comment: @LucaKiebel its in the title?

Comment: @apxx He wants to know why you want to reverse the array!

Comment: 2 thousand is not very big. My library goodcore uses one of the temp swap algorithms in the link and I can easily handle much much larger arrays than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you just read the array in reverse instead of reversing it? You could also create a wrapper class around Array e.g., `ReversibleArray` which uses the same backing array instance but could be read forwards or backwards depending on some property like `readInReverse: true|false` on instances of that class.